# Saving an Html DATA in mysql and still output a html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im saving an HTML data in mysql, should i use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

and how do i output it so it still in html?

I tried outputing it with `htmlspecialchars()` but the image source are not working. There are still some `\&quot;` included.

```
$saveDate = array( 
                            'title' =>   mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['title'] ), 
                            'message' => mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['content']), 

                        ); 
    $this->wpdb->insert('wp_message', $saveDate);
```

what is the better way to save an html data so still get the html for my output?

Comment: Do you want to display all HTML content that you insert into the DB?

Comment: yes, .but the html i display  is wrong. it has this `\&quot;`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will convert `HTML` tags to html entities. If you want to output HTML tags, then don't use `htmlspecialchars`. Just echo out the raw database output.